# Pre-Order induced by continuous functions

Tags: ct.category-theory, order-theory, limits-and-colimits

I'm an newbie in category theory, but I want use it to solve a pre-order question I encountered in my research:

Let $X$ be a convex&compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. $f,g: X \rightarrow [0,1]$ are continous functions. I can define three pre-order categories $\mathbb{C}_f,\mathbb{C}_g, \mathbb{C}_{f,g}$ on $X$. Their objects are $X$, and their pre-order relations given by:
$$\forall x,y \in X, x=(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n),y=(y_1,y_2,\dots,y_n)$$
$$x_2=y_2,x_3=y_3,\dots,x_n=y_n, f(x) \le f(y) \Rightarrow (x,y)\in R_f$$
$$x_1=y_1,x_3=y_3,\dots,x_n=y_n, f(x) \le f(y) \Rightarrow (x,y)\in R_g$$
$$R_{f,g} = R_f \cup R_g$$
And the morphisms is generated by completion of $R_f,R_g,R_{f,g}$

So both $\mathbb{C}_f,\mathbb{C}_g$ are just subcategory of $\mathbb{C}_{f,g}$, and the trivial functor between $\mathbb{C}_f$ and $\mathbb{C}_{f,g}$ is order-preserving. In fact $\mathbb{C}_{f,g}$ is the category product of $\mathbb{C}_f$ and $\mathbb{C}_g$.

Now consider the maximum objects $M_f$in $\mathbb{C}_f$(up to isomorphism), they are the limits of category 2. Can I prove that $M_f \cap M_{f,g} \ne \emptyset$ ? Or is their any counter-example in which it is empty?

Base on my very limited knowledge, I feel it may be related to Lawvere's fixed point theorem, but I don't know how to form the connection.

Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: I don't follow your notation.  If you only have a preorder then it would be better to say glb, inf or meet rather than limit and order-preserving function rather than functor.   Presumably the objects of the preorders are the *points* of $X$ and you are defining $x\leq_f y$ where $x,y\in X$?  The subscripts look confused. What is $R_f$?

Comment: As defined, $R_{f,g}$ does not seem to be transitive.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Yes, $R_{f,g}$ is not necessarily transitive, thus I phrased it as "morphisms generated by completion of $R_{f,g}$".

Comment: @PaulTaylor Sorry for the long and confusing notation. $\mathbb{R}_f$ is just $\le_f$. So $x\le_f y$ if $f(x)\le f(y)$ and $x,y$ only differ in first dimension.

Comment: I believe that this conjecture is false for reasons of easy real analysis (or order theory).  I also consider that the categorical language is obfuscating the problem. (Note that I am a categorist saying this.)

Comment: @PaulTaylor In fact $M_f, M_g$ are compact and $M_f \cap M_g \ne \emptyset$ due to kakutani's fixed point theorem. I just don't know how to include $M_{f,g}$ in the picture.